# Heroku python-telegram-bot but shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram' "

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

I installed python-telegram-bot on virtual-env and imported it by `from telegram.ext import *`, but it won't work on Heroku. I run `python3 main.py` on the Heroku console but I faced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'
```

The `requirement.txt` is:

```
APScheduler==3.6.3
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.10.8
click==8.1.2
Flask==2.1.1
importlib-metadata==4.11.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
python-telegram-bot==13.11
pytz==2022.1
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
six==1.16.0
tornado==6.1
tzdata==2022.1
tzlocal==4.2
Werkzeug==2.1.1
zipp==3.8.0
```

And the Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
"backports.zoneinfo" = "==0.2.1"
cachetools = "==4.2.2"
certifi = "==2021.10.8"
click = "==8.1.2"
importlib-metadata = "==4.11.3"
itsdangerous = "==2.1.2"
python-telegram-bot = "==13.11"
pytz = "==2022.1"
pytz-deprecation-shim = "==0.1.0.post0"
six = "==1.16.0"
tornado = "==6.1"
tzdata = "==2022.1"
tzlocal = "==4.2"
zipp = "==3.8.0"
APScheduler = "==3.6.3"
Flask = "==2.1.1"
Jinja2 = "==3.1.1"
MarkupSafe = "==2.1.1"
Werkzeug = "==2.1.1"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Also the `Pipfile.lock` have this part:

```
        "python-telegram-bot": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:534f5bb0ff4ca34c9252e97e0b3bcdab81d97be0eb4821682a361cb426c00e55",
                "sha256:baeff704baa2ac3dc17a944c02da888228ad258e89be2e5bcbd13a8a5102d573"
            ],
            "index": "pypi",
            "version": "==13.11"
        },
```

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile`?

Comment: That is impossible to read in a comment. Please [edit] it into your question. And please also check your `Pipfile.lock` for a `python-telegram-bot` entry. I suspect you haven't got one.

Comment: Because you have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, Heroku will ignore your `requirements.txt` entirely. It is irrelevant. Are you _entirely sure_ that this `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` are committed, and that you deployed that commit to Heroku's `main` or `master` branch?

Comment: @Chris Yep, I committed those two files to Heroku `master` branch.

Comment: And when you deploy, do you see the `python-telegram-bot` library getting installed? Deployment succeeds? Those files are in the root directory of your project?

Comment: @Chris Yes, everything was fine.